# I am using Auto route dependency to route from one page to another page. I am constantly being notified by the error

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am using Auto route dependency to route from one page to another page. While i a was writing the code eventhough i added the route dependencies i am being notified by this error.

@MaterialAutoRouter(routes:[
MaterialRoute(page: SplashPage, initial: true),
MaterialRoute(page: SignInPage),
MaterialRoute(page: StarredReposPage),
])
class $AppRouter{}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyM4X.png)

i trired changing the dependencies versions but there is of no use.In vs code i am unable to see the Suggestion for "@MaterialAutoRoute".

Answer (score 0):

are you using the latest version of the package?

Have you added the package at the top of the line?

If you are using the **latest package version**

it should be like:

```
@AutoRouterConfig()      
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {      
   
@override      
RouteType get defaultRouteType => RouteType.material(); //.cupertino, .adaptive ..etc    
   
 @override      
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [      
  /// routes go here     
  ]    
}
```

If you are using the **old package version** it
it should be like:

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Screen,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[]
....
```

Kindly refer to the documentation for auto_route:
https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route

The **migration to v6** have changed some config:
https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#migrating-to-v6